# undefined method `friendly' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I recently installed `friendly_id` 5 on my Rails 4 app. I've followed the quick start guide, and setup a model like this:

```
class Official::Master < Official
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :history]

end
```

When I try to save an Official::Master, however, I get this error:

```
undefined method `friendly' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

This happens in the `create` controller action:

```
def create
  official = Official::Master.new(official_params)
  official.save # error occurs on this line
end
```

Unfortunately, Rails isn't producing a stack trace, which it typically does. I'm at a loss for how to troubleshoot this error.

UPDATE:

Removed the backtrace silencers and got this:

> activerecord (4.0.1) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:121:in
>   `method_missing' activerecord (4.0.1)
>   lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:68:in`method_missing'
>   friendly_id (5.0.1) lib/friendly_id/slugged.rb:302:in
>   `scope_for_slug_generator' friendly_id (5.0.1)
>   lib/friendly_id/history.rb:104:in`scope_for_slug_generator'
>   friendly_id (5.0.1) lib/friendly_id/slugged.rb:313:in `slug_generator'
>   friendly_id (5.0.1) lib/friendly_id/slugged.rb:294:in`set_slug'

Looks like the error is on line 302 of slugged.rb:

```
scope = scope.friendly unless friendly_id_config.uses? :finders
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is seems that friendlyid 5 not yet handling single table inheritance in rails 4 correctly. What happens if you put the code below to the parent class?

```
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :history]
```

And here is an issue that address more or less the same problem: [Friendly_id 5 rc1 - single table inheritance issue](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/issues/447)

Comment: Thank you, that's definitely the cause of the bug. Unfortunately, this solution isn't viable in my use-case, as the other models that inherent from Official should not have friendly ids. Still, it's good know what's going on.

Comment: Actually, it looks like the link you provided has some suggestions for how to handle this. Got everything working with that hint.